# Javascript sending only one message over websocket in browser

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have a websocketserver running on a ESP32 which works perfect.

My problem is that if I send a message to the server over a website the socketserver on the ESP32 executes the .send(message) only the first time and is not sending anymore any message.

If I send a message from the developertools/console in chrome it works every time.

At this point I suppose my problem seems not to be on the server-side but on the client-side.

This is my html/javascript-code running inside chrome:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>WH_Quiz</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: url(Images/SET_1/A1_INTRO.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>


    <script>
        // clear localStorage
        window.localStorage.clear();

        // open websocket
        var url = "ws://192.168.4.1:1337";
        websocket = new WebSocket(url);
        websocket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log('websocket is open');
            websocket.send("L");
        };
        
        
        // Keep track of clicked keys
        var isKeyPressed = {
            'a': false, // ASCII code for 'a'
            'b': false, // ASCII code for 'b'
            // ... Other keys to check for custom key combinations
        };

        document.onkeydown = (keyDownEvent) => {

            // Prevent default key actions, if desired
            keyDownEvent.preventDefault();

            // Track down key click
            isKeyPressed[keyDownEvent.key] = true;

            // Check described custom shortcut
            if (isKeyPressed['a']) { //for example we want to check if a is clicked
                //do something 
                console.log('a has been pressed');

                websocket.onopen = function (event) {
                    console.log('a has been pressed and wesocket is open');
                    window.location.href = '1_1.html'; // öffne Fragenkatalog 1
                    websocket.send("4G");
                };

            };
            // Check described custom shortcut
             if (isKeyPressed['b']) { //for example we want to check if b is clicked
                //do something 
                console.log('b has been pressed');
                                
                websocket.onopen = function (event) {
                    window.location.href = '2_1.html'; // öffne Fragenkatalog 2
                    websocket.send("4R");
                };
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In my console logs I can see that it enters the "isKeyPressed" if-statement but it is not executing the "websocket.onopen = function (event)".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`websocket.onopen` is only triggered the first time the socket is open. Since it's already open at this point, you should be able to just directly call the send function.

In other words:

```
if (isKeyPressed['b']) { //for example we want to check if b is clicked
  //do something 
  console.log('b has been pressed');
                                
  websocket.onopen = function (event) {
    window.location.href = '2_1.html'; // öffne Fragenkatalog 2
    websocket.send("4R");
  };
};
```

becomes:

```
if (isKeyPressed['b']) { //for example we want to check if b is clicked
  //do something 
  console.log('b has been pressed');          
  window.location.href = '2_1.html'; // öffne Fragenkatalog 2
  websocket.send("4R");          
};
```

Comment: As the whole project is made of a few sites do I have to open and close the websocket connection everytime I leave one site and open the next one or once opened the connection stays open till I close the browser?

Comment: The socket will remain open while you're within the same page load. If you have a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) the socket would remain open while you navigate within the context of the SPA.

If going to a new page requests a brand new HTML page, the socket will need to be created again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about websockets but it looks like the onopen() function is like the onready() function in discord.js. It only runs when the script is started/ the websocket is opened.